# Hyperlinks in Atom not clickable?

Tags: python, atom-editor

this may come off as a noob question but I am watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzoTFD-wzdY&t=122s) (skip to 0:46) and figured I would attempt to try the project.
What I am trying to do is basically make a simple username generator.

Watching the video I couldn't help but notice that the person in the video has the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominictarr/random-name/master/first-names.txt'

r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text

print(text)
```

In the video, the link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dominictarr/random-name/master/first-names.txt
looks to be a clickable link.

In my Atom IDE, my link does not appear to be clickable even though the code executes perfectly.

Just a weird thing I ran into, wasn't sure this would have anything to do with my python version or Atom. [Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqItp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Ctrl + click
In Vs-Code also to open links you have to hold down Ctrl and click on the link.
In Atom , it might be the same.
Hope it solves your problem

Comment: That did it! just curious would there be a way for the code to always show it as a hyperlinked text?

Comment: I guess it would